# How to remove / change window title bar to make XP look like Windows 7?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

Is there any way of changing or removing the text in the Windows XP window title bars?

I want it to look like Windows 7 or Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not possible without any theme. Download [Themes](http://www.dkszone.net/20-best-visual-themes-for-windows-xp) for windows XP and enjoy the look. And you can also download [Aston](http://www.astonshell.com/) its pretty cool tool for changing themes on XP. [Windows Blind](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) is another cool tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows 7 provides lots of new features along with a newly designed interface. It looks very similar to Windows Vista but there are many GUI changes like redesigned taskbar, Explorer, new boot screen and login screen, etc.

If you are still using Windows XP but want to enjoy the new Windows 7 look, then this tutorial will definitely help you.

After following this tutorial, you'll get the same Windows 7 look in your Windows XP. Following is a list of things which are going to change after following this tutorial:

```
Windows Theme or Visual Style
Icons
Boot Screen
Login Screen or Welcome Screen
Sounds
Cursors
Taskbar
Wallpaper
Sidebar
Progress Dialog Box
Shutdown / Log off Dialog Box
About Windows Box
System Properties Dialog Box
Volume Control Window
Extras like "Aero Shake", "Aero Snap", "Aero Peek", "Calculator" and "Paint"
A Few Other Mods...

NOTE 1: If you want to download all BITMAPs, AVIs and other files mentioned in this tutorial in a single pack, you can download it using this link.

NOTE 2: Please create a Restore point using "System Restore" before applying anything mentioned in this tutorial so that you can restore your system back to default if you don't like the changes.

Also take a backup of system files before modifying them, so that you can restore them if anything goes wrong or you don't like the new change.

NOTE 3: If you are facing problems while saving a file after editing in resource hacker, then make sure you have disabled WFP (Windows File Protection) service using "WFP Patcher" or use "Replacer" to replace the file. Both utilities can be found in our "Download" section.

Also if you are getting error "Can't create file...", that means you have edited and saved the same file in past and there is a backup file which needs to be deleted before saving this file again. Go to the folder containing this file and you'll see a similar file having "_original" in its name. Delete it and try to save the file in resource hacker.
```

[Here](http://www.askvg.com/transform-windows-xp-into-windows-7-without-using-customization-pack/) you can find how to do it.

:D

Comment: I can't find where it is

Comment: Naked links aren't useful as answers. Please summarise the relevant information here just in case the link goes stale.